# "subscript out of bounds error" when trying to knit to .md file? How to fix?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown

my rmarkdown file seems to have an issue knitting on this specific chunk of code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(female = c("Republican", "Republican", "Democrat", "Democrat"),
                 male = c("Republican", "Democrat", "Republican", "Democrat"),
                 n = c(100, 50, 50, 150))

xtabs(n ~ female + male, df)
#             male
# female      Democrat     Republican
#  Democrat        150     50
#  Republican       50     100
```

I am trying to calculate the probability of a Rep Female being with a Rep Man, and vice versa. So in this example that would be (100 / 150), but I don't know how to do that in a relation to the variables.

I tried this:

```
Fem <- colSums(df[ , "Republican", drop = FALSE] ) / sum(colSums(df))
Fem
Men <- rowSums(df["Republican", , drop = FALSE ] ) / sum(rowSums(df))
Men
```

This works fine in the code and produces probabilities, but refuses to compile when I try to knit it into an md file. It says:

```
Error in `[.default`(df, , "Republican", drop = FALSE) : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... colSums -> -> is.data.frame -> [ -> [.table -> NextMethod
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.5.2
2: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.5.2
3: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.5.2
Execution Halted
```

Could someone help me decipher where I messed up? Thank you!

Comment: `df["Republican",]` only works if there are row names, your sample data does not. Do you mean `df[ df$female == "Republican",,drop=FALSE]`? (Does that code work on the console, regardless of rmarkdown? I suggest when making your rmarkdown documents, you try things on the console before trying to automate and render your report.)

Comment: The code I provided works well for me on the console :/ It automatically generated row names for me. Your solution gives me this error: "Error in df$female : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: There must be code that you are not sharing, since that error occurs when `df` is not a frame. Are you by chance overwriting with `df <- xtabs(...)`? That's rather important. More the point, `data.frame` does not auto-generate row names like that, and that's the only place you are assigning to `df`.)

Comment: And btw, in the future please only include calls to `library` when you actually are using it. In this case, the uber-huge `tidyverse` is not used. (As a courtesy, if you can figure it out, it helps to only include the specific components from the `tidyverse` that you are actually using, such as `dplyr`, `tidyr`, `purrr` among the top 10. This is all part of the exercise of generating a concise and reproducible question.)

Comment: I promise that that's all the code I've used. And sorry about tidyverse, I only put it there since I know it's loaded and didn't know if it would affect the issue.

Comment: **Something is missing**, of that I am confident. If you start a new R session (don't reload a cache! make sure the environment is empty with `ls()`), then type in your code *as you present it here*, you will get errors or warnings different from your question. Your assertion only makes sense (so far) if you do `df<-data.frame(...)` and then `df<-xtabs(...,data=df)`. Further, if it is the table and not the frame, `df["Republican",,drop=F]` gets you the republicans, not the males (or females), so your summary statistic is mis-informing.

Comment: Good point on including `tidyverse` in case it would affect the issue ... it *can* affect things adversely (or positively), specifically with masking of functions. Namely: `filter` and `lag` have caused people angst, either expecting base behavior with `dplyr` loaded or vice-versa if not loaded.